# Нужно ли учиться писать такой код сразу?

Tags: c++

или это не очень то уж и нужно?
Например:

```
void setFrame(int l_frame)
{
if(m_currentFrame != l_frame)
m_currentFrame=l_frame;
}
```

Нежели

```
void setFrame(int l_frame)
{
m_currentFrame=l_frame;
}
```

Comment: А зачем?! 8-/ Нет, допускаю, что для каких-то классов, где присвоение написано так, что имеет побочные действия, там и может быть нужно, но так классы лучше не писать... Да, а вот форматировать код и не прижимать все к левому краю - таки нужно...

Comment: @Harry, чтобы писать сразу оптимизированный код. Мне легче писать просто работающий код для начала а потом уже редактировать.

Comment: "Преждевременная оптимизация  - корень всех бед" (с) Кнут :)

Comment: Первый вариант имеет количество обращений к памяти 1-2 раза. А второй только один раз. Без сравнения будет меньше нагрузки на канал памяти.

Comment: Так как самоприсваивание потенциально может быть логической ошибкой, то как первый, так и второй варианты потенциально  могут работать неправильно. Первый тихо избегает самоприсваивания, второй просто игнорирует. Это особо актульно для конструкторов. Еще может быть, что такой сеттер потенциально должен уведомлять об изменении значения. Также в первом варианте можно поставить точку останова на изменение.

Comment: @Harry, а например если код изображает картинку только тогда когда пользователь эту картинку видит? Это тоже считается за преждевременную оптимизацию?

Comment: См. мое *"допускаю, что для каких-то классов, где присвоение написано так, что имеет побочные действия, там и может быть нужно, но так классы лучше не писать"*. Сомневаюсь, что *приведенный код* в состоянии приводить к выводу картинки...